RM Anova or 2 paired t-tests ? And verifying for individual differences with RCI
For a research project evaluating the changes in cognitive abilities after anesthesia using tests that record the reaction time to a stimulus, we tested our subjects on baseline, 1 hour and 4 hours post-anesthesia, so three times in total. The study aims to tell whether it's dangerous to drive after this anesthesia or not.
Are RM Anovas or paired t-tests better suited to compare those 3 moments ? Another research similar to hours used RM Anovas, but I fear on losing statistical power. The positive of the RM Anova is that it's more presentable, and I can add inter-subjects factors in my analysis (such as their metabolism for the absorption of the anesthetic).
Second question, as we deal with safety issues, it is important to report if even a single person is affected negatively with the sedation. For this, I decided to go for a Reliable Change Index for now, but I am unsure if that's the best choice, as I don't have the test-retest reliability at hand. I used this formula: calculate_RCI <- function(M1, SD1, M2, SD2) {return((M1 - M2) / sqrt(SD1^2 + SD2^2))}
Is it better to use the SD of the whole group, or the SD of the individual at the different points in time ?
